# Web UI Automation Localization/Globalization testing

Tags: c#, localization, globalization, ui-automation, cultureinfo

I am new to localization\globalization testing. I would like to test my current Web UI application on the same.

I am using Selenium driver to drive my automation using C# language.

Basically, I would like to check the text like control names or label names or anything that is related to text on a page. I have added a .Resx file which has text strings like for an example consider a Google search page, which has a button with text "Google Search". So I have added a string "GoogleSearch" and its value as "Google Search". And I configure the culture in my App.Config file.

```
   public static CultureInfo GetCulture()
    {
        string selectedLanguage = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CurrentCulture"];

        CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(selectedLanguage);

        return cultureInfo;
    }
```

Based on the config settings I am picking the culture like ja-JP (Japanese) or etc. But when I try to pick the text of Google Search text it always shows "Google Search".

```
   string gSearch =  ResSearchPage.ResourceManager.GetString("GoogleSearch", GetCulture());
```

Here, ResSearchPage class is the file which holds the 'GoogleSearch' string.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance,
Sham_

Comment: When you pick ja-JP what were you expecting?

Comment: I would expect the string 'Google Search' to be translated to Japanese string.

Comment: I dont want to add translated file for different cultures. Suppose if I add translated file, then I need to add the other translated files as well for different cultures. Instead I need to return the translated file based on the culture I set in GetClutlure() method.

Comment: Well you cant, you need translated file. If such system existed people would not spending billions in translating software! Bottom line you need translated file.

Comment: ** Thanks special scope**. But still I have a clarification. If translated file are mandatory then why do we need

`GSearch.Culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ja-JP");
            ResourceManager rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("LocalizationTest.GSearch", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            string search = rm.GetString("Search", GSearch.Culture);
            string lucky = rm.GetString("FellingLucky", GSearch.Culture);`

Comment: To automatically fetch the translate files. Most of frameworks are configured in such a way that the language files are automatically selected after the user's locale has been detected. Read this to get basic idea http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization
In your example you use resource manager to fetch appropriate language file. Generally you need to name files like en-US,ja-JP etc.